# configuring dhcp with dynaminc ipv4 and ipv6 address

Tags: dhcp, ipv6, dhcpd, dynamic-ip

i just want to know that is that possible to configure dynamic ipv4 and ipv6 address on eth1. i tried ipv4 is working but ipv6 doesn't. if yes then how.

If not then what should i do. Because i want to deliver both dynamic address to clients connected to dhcp server.

need help 
thnks

Comment: Ask your ISP to provide you IPv6 service. You will not get IPv6 addresses until your ISP provides connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

If the network supports IPv6, it should automatically get one.  If you're not getting one, and you know that the network supports IPv6, then you might need to disable IPv4 altogether, so you only have IPv6.

If you're using the GUI to configure eth1, then you might also want to try selecting "Require IPv6 address to complete connection" in the IPv6 page.